# JSON and Main.storyboard - swift 2

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, xcode7

I want to create a  website blocking app where parents can block any website they want by typing the link or any tags into UITextField. I can't work out how to have the user enter the links/tags into a UITextField ( i only know how to manually add the links/tags by accessing the .JSON file
 in the code.

Any help would be appreciated,
thx,
Noja

P.S. The below code is in the .JSON file

```
[
{
    "action": {
        "type": "block"
    },
    "trigger": {
        "url-filter": "example"
    }
}

]
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. A `UITextField` is for entering values (such as links), so what do you mean you can't figure out how to have the user enter the links/tags into the textfield?

Comment: so i want the user to enter tags in the textfield and the tags entered will transferred to a JSON file @SylvanDAsh

Comment: so have the users enter tags separated by a special character e.g. `;` or `,` and then when they submit the values, get the textfield's value, break up the string using the special character and you'll have your values

Comment: yes but i can't attach a uitextfield to a .JSON file @SylvanDAsh

Comment: What do you mean by "attach"? There is no `magic` way to have these two linked so that changes made in the text field will be automatically reflected in the JSON. You need to read the file into memory, process it (adding/removing/changing the links) and then save it again. Also bear in mind, that there already is a system way to achieve this : http://www.imore.com/how-block-specific-websites-being-accessed-safari-iphone-and-ipad

Comment: You can either add a `ADD button` for the user to click to add tags/links that calls your function to do the breaking up and stuff **OR** implement the `valueChanged` listener for the textfield